# Is CROSS APPLY the correct method to join a table with no unique identifier for all rows (duplicate records)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am pretty new to SQL. I am trying to join two tables, tblEmployeeHours and tblWages. However, the Wages table can contain duplicate rows.

Here is a snippet of the EmployeeHours table:

```
x--------------x-------------x---------x-------x
| ReportDate   |  DeptCode   |  EmpID  | Hours |
x--------------x-------------x---------x-------x
|  12/31/2017  |     A       | 112233  |  240  |
|  6/30/2018   |     A       | 112233  |  390  |
|  12/31/2017  |     A       | 224466  |  422  |
|  6/30/2018   |     B       | 334455  |  390  |
x--------------x-------------x---------x-------x
```

And the Wages table:

```
x----------x--------------x-------------x
| EmpID    |  CostCenter  |  HourlyWage |
x----------x--------------x-------------x
|  112233  |  Engineering |     24.0    |
|  112233  |  Engineering |     35.0    |
|  334455  |    Field     |     42.2    |
|  334455  |    Field     |     42.2    |
x----------x--------------x-------------x
```

Since there is no real unique identifier in the Wages table, nor an effective date for the hourly wage in the Wages table (which I think is the bigger issue for me in this case), how can I make sure that I am computing the paycheck amount (HourlyWage x Hours) with the correct hourly wage? *Let's assume that wages are in chronological order.*

So, for example, for employee 112233, 24.0 is the old wage and 35.0 is the most recent wage. I want to use $35.0/hr to calculate his paycheck for 6/30/2018, and $24/hr for his 12/31/2017 paycheck.

I thought that maybe a CROSS APPLY would do the trick with a TOP 1 *, but that will still return only the first (old) wage of $24.

```
select e.ReportDate, e.EmpID, e.Hours, tw.HourlyWage
from tblEmployeeHours e
cross apply
    ( select top 1 *
    from tblWages w
    where w.EmpID = e.EmpID
    ) tw
```

Results:

```
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
| ReportDate   |  EmpID   |  Hours | HourlyWage |
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
|  12/31/2017  |  112233  |   240  |     24     |
|  6/30/2018   |  112233  |   390  |     24     |
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
```

Desired results:

```
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
| ReportDate   |  EmpID   |  Hours | HourlyWage |
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
|  12/31/2017  |  112233  |   240  |     24     |
|  6/30/2018   |  112233  |   390  |   **35**   |
x--------------x----------x--------x------------x
```

Comment: Question, how do you express in the query which one is the new wage?  Seems like you know, but for the database those are just numbers. And I don't see an order by in the cross apply query.  Perhaps that Wages table could use a startdate and an enddate column?

Comment: As a general principal, all tables should have a prime key column, which then enables relationships between tables to work.

Comment: @LukStorms, agreed about the need for startdate/enddate columns. Unfortunately, I did not create the database, and I don't have permissions to edit/update tables. And I don't have a way to know for sure which one is the new wage either. So at this point I'm just looking for a way to "force" the 1st wage to be the old wage, and the 2nd wage to be the new wage for each employee.

Comment: So then I guess moving the old wages to another table and then deleting them from the Wages table isn't an option either. (and neither putting a unique index on Wages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (Quick & Dirty, please clean up). This should give you an idea. Note: The query is written for the specific data here (see inserts). **This is NOT the exact answer**. I just want to give you an idea of where to start - Combine CTEs, Cross/Outer Apply, Windowing, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeHours (
ReportDate SMALLDATETIME,
DeptCode VARCHAR(1),
EmpID INT,
[Hours] INT
)

CREATE TABLE Wages (
EmpID INT,
CostCenter VARCHAR(25),
HourlyWage DECIMAL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeHours
(
    ReportDate,
    DeptCode,
    EmpID,
    Hours
)
VALUES
('12/31/2017', 'A', 112233, 240   ),
('6/30/2018', 'A', 112233, 390  ),
('12/31/2017', 'A', 224466, 422   ),
('6/30/2018', 'B', 334455, 390   )

INSERT INTO dbo.Wages
(
    EmpID,
    CostCenter,
    HourlyWage
)
VALUES
(  112233, 'Engineering', 24.0 ),
(  112233, 'Engineering', 35.0 ),
(  334455, 'Field', 42.2 ),
(  334455, 'Field', 42.2 )

--Query
    WITH EmployeeWage AS (SELECT eh.ReportDate, eh.EmpID, eh.[Hours], w.HourlyWage
                      FROM dbo.EmployeeHours eh
                           JOIN Wages w ON eh.EmpID=w.EmpID)
,EmployeeWageChage AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.empid, x.hourlywage, a.ReportDate
                    ORDER BY a.ReportDate, a.empid, x.HourlyWage) AS row_num, a.*
                    FROM EmployeeWage a
                    CROSS APPLY(SELECT HourlyWage FROM wages)x )
, result AS (SELECT DISTINCT reportDate, EmpID, Hours, HourlYwage
             FROM EmployeeWageChage z
             WHERE z.row_num=1)
, final AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY reportdate, empid, hours ORDER BY reportdate, empid) AS rn, *
           FROM result)
SELECT reportdate, empid, Hours, HourlyWage FROM final WHERE rn=1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering.  No "chronological" order or otherwise.

This method:

```
select e.ReportDate, e.EmpID, e.Hours, tw.HourlyWage
from tblEmployeeHours e cross apply
     (select top 1 *
      from tblWages w
      where w.EmpID = e.EmpID
     ) tw;
```

Arbitrarily chooses an *arbitrary* matching row.  You really need:

```
select e.ReportDate, e.EmpID, e.Hours, tw.HourlyWage
from tblEmployeeHours e cross apply
     (select top 1 *
      from tblWages w
      where w.EmpID = e.EmpID
      order by w.effective_date -- or whatever column goes here
     ) tw;
```

If you have an `identity` column or `dateCreated` column, then chose could be used (for instance).

You *could* assume that wages always go up, and use `order by w.HourlyWage desc`, but that might not be true for this application.

Comment: there is no effective_date column or anything else, unfortunately. So at this point I was looking for ways to "force" the Wages table to have row numbers, at least temporarily, so that I could see a different wage for each report date. Although I know that that is probably not the correct approach, since I would be relying on the order in which hourly wage is returned, without knowing for sure that the top row will always be the old wage, and the next row will be the new wage.

Comment: @eggman . . . If you just want a different row, you can use `order by newid()`.  However, SQL Server does not have a reliable way of ordering the rows chronologically.  It is simply outside the definition of a table.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *chronological order* in a table, but I would assume that wages increase over time (hopefully).

Then you could assign a row_number to both tables:

```
;WITH EmployeeHourRN AS 
 (
   SELECT * 
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY empid
            ORDER BY ReportDate desc) as rn
   FROM dbo.EmployeeHours
 )
,WagesRN AS
 (
   SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() -- assuming wages increase over time
      OVER (PARTITION BY empid
            ORDER BY HourlyWage desc) AS rn
            FROM wages
 )
select *
from EmployeeHourRN as e
left join WagesRN as w
  on e.empid = w.empid
 and e.rn = w.rn
```

Of course this will not work if there are more rows (per empid) in EmployeeHour than in wages. And which wage should be assigned to empid 224466? The Left Join will show both problems, see [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb39cf004fd0331a531b2f8adddd866f)